# Test device is moving or not by accelerometer in titanium

Tags: android, titanium, accelerometer, titanium-mobile, accelerator

As question title, I want to use the change values of accelerator at three axis x,y,z to test that device is standing still or is moving.
I can use titanium to get values of accelerator in 3 axis:

```
 Ti.Accelerometer.addEventListenter('update',function(e))
 {
    var x=e.x;
    var y=e.y;
    var z=e.z;
    var timestamp=e.timestamp;
 }
```

In real device, those values change continuously. I want to calculate the change between two times update consecutive. But I need some pointers on how to do the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

How about in `addEventListener` you keep 3 `static` variables or a single `static` structure containing the last values and calculate the `abs()` difference on them and the current values?

Pseudo code ( handling just one variable - expand to three ):

```
int f( int x )
{
    static int old_x = -1;

    if( x != old_x )
    { 
         // movement detected and do something
         old_x = x;
    }
    else
    {
         // no movement
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you can use Ti.App.Properties variables to store values if you want.  Instead of your pseudocode's c++ style static variable, use a property and update it at the end of your event listener.

http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.8.2/Titanium.App.Properties-module